# Create dependant record on Clearance user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, clearance

I simply want to create another record when the user signs up. I think the following are the only places where Clearance touches my app, not counting the views.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Clearance::Controller
  before_action :require_login
  .
  .
  .
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Clearance::User
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :receiver_id
  has_one :privilege
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `after_create` (or perhaps `before_create`, or some other hook, depending on your semantics), which is provided by Rails independent of Clearance. It lets you declare a method to run after your `User` record is created, and the method can create other objects that you want to exist.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_other_thing

  private

  def create_other_thing
    OtherThing.create(other_thing_attributes)
  end
end
```

Be aware than `after_create` runs in the same transaction as your `User` creation, so if there's an exception during `OtherThing.create`, both it and the `User` will be rolled back.

Check out [Active Record Callbacks](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for full details on how ActiveRecord lifecycle hooks work.